# issue with running Angle - Bootstrap Admin app (angular-meteor version): TypeError: $browser.addPollFn is not a function angular-cookies.js:60

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

just purchased Angle - Bootstrap Admin app from wrapbootstrap

Tried to run the angular-meteor version of the app

The first issue was that meteor did not like the contents of the default index.html, so I renamed the file to be index.ng.html

Now the error I'm getting in the browser console is:

```
TypeError: $browser.addPollFn is not a function angular-cookies.js:60
```

What can be done to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about wrapbootstrap, but generally this error means you are using incompatible versions of angular and angular-cookies.
The external angular modules you use (e.g. ngAnimate, ngCookies, ngResource, ngRoute etc), should always be the same version as angular.

Comment: truly true! Thank you for this safe me life

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be Resolved by using same Version of `angular.min.js` and `angular-cookies.js`.

*It always good to use same version of files*